# How to have synchronous ES6 imports

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

Because of a module in ES6, I had to migrate my whole application to ES6.

Except that now, because import is asynchronous, I have a problem in the flow of my code.

index.js

```
import joi from 'joi';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
const config = dotenv.config();
if (config.error) {
    console.error(config.error);
    process.exit(1);
}
const configError = joi.object({
    HTTP_URL_FRONT: joi.string().uri().required(),
    JWT_SECRET: joi.string().required(),
    DIR_DATA: joi.string().required(),
    DIR_TMP: joi.string().required(),
    MONGODB_URI: joi.string().required()
}).required().validate(config.parsed).error;
if (configError) {
    console.error(".env invalide", configError);
    process.exit(1);
}

console.log("1", process.env.HTTP_URL_FRONT)
import './services/mongoose.service.js';
console.log("3", process.env.HTTP_URL_FRONT)
```

services/mongoose.service.js

```
console.log("2", process.env.HTTP_URL_FRONT);
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

(async function () {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
})().catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
    process.exit(1);
});

export default mongoose;
```

The result

```
2 undefined
1 http://localhost
3 http://localhost
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

As you can see, the import is done before, which breaks the connection to Mongo. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Only _dynamic_ imports are asynchronous. Your Mongoose service makes no sense, why doesn't it expose a _function_ to connect?

Comment: I replaced export default mongoose by export async function connect
Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using top-level await and `await import('./services/mongoose.service.js');` in the line where you want the import to happen, but what I would recommend instead is to properly declare the dependency of your mongoose service on the loaded configuration:

```
// config.js
import joi from 'joi';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
const config = dotenv.config();
if (config.error) {
    throw config.error;
}
const configError = joi.object({
    HTTP_URL_FRONT: joi.string().uri().required(),
    JWT_SECRET: joi.string().required(),
    DIR_DATA: joi.string().required(),
    DIR_TMP: joi.string().required(),
    MONGODB_URI: joi.string().required()
}).required().validate(config.parsed).error;
if (configError) {
    throw new Error(".env invalide", {cause: configError});
}
console.log("1", config.parsed.HTTP_URL_FRONT)
export default config.parsed;
```

```
// services/mongoose.service.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import config from '../config.js';
console.log("2", config.HTTP_URL_FRONT);

await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);

export default mongoose;
```

```
// index.js

import './services/mongoose.service.js';
console.log("3: config loaded and mongoose connected")
```